# Need help on PHP array filtering

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in php, i want to select all casenumber those have dob and then select all links those not have any dob. How can I do that in php

```
Array
(
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => inquiryDetail.jis?caseId=0101SP085622015&loc=3&detailLoc=DV
            [1] => inquiryDetail.jis?caseId=0101SP096462015&loc=3&detailLoc=DV
            [2] => inquiryDetail.jis?caseId=050200173642014&loc=20&detailLoc=DSCIVIL
            [3] => inquiryDetail.jis?caseId=CAL1432003&loc=65&detailLoc=PGV
        )
    [case_number] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0101SP085622015
            [1] => 0101SP096462015
            [2] => 050200173642014
            [3] => CAL1432003
        )
    [persons] => Array
        (
            [0] => Walker, Rosemary
            [1] => Walker, Rosemary
            [2] => Walker, Rosemary
            [3] => Walker, Rosemary
        )
    [dob] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11/1961
            [1] => 11/1961
        )
    [Party_Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => Defendant
            [1] => Defendant
            [2] => Defendant
            [3] => Defendant
        )

    [Court] => Array
        (
            [0] => Baltimore City District Court 1400 North Ave.
            [1] => Baltimore City District Court 1400 North Ave.
            [2] => Upper Marlboro District Court
            [3] => Prince George\'s County Circuit Court
        )
    [Case_Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => Domestic Violence
            [1] => Domestic Violence
            [2] => CONT
            [3] => CIVIL
        )

    [Case_Status] => Array
        (
            [0] => CLOSE
            [1] => CLOSE
            [2] => ACTIVE
            [3] => ACTIVE
        )
    [Filing_Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09/04/2015
            [1] => 11/25/2015
            [2] => 07/24/2014
            [3] => 11/18/2014
        )

)
```

Here all are inter connected with keys to each other. please help

Answer (score 0):

This solutuon works if indexes of each subarrays match. If not, you should clarify your question with associations between subarrays.

$array - your input data.

You'll get $result array which contains searched values.

```
$result = array(
   'links_without_dob' => array(),
   'case_number_with_dob' => array() 
);
foreach($array['dob'] as $k => $v) {
  $result['case_number_with_dob'][] = $array['case_number'][$k];
}
foreach($array['links'] as $k => $v) {
  if (array_key_exists($k, $array['dob'])) continue;
  $result['links_without_dob'][] = $v;
}
```

I'll be glad to see any suggestions for improving this solution.